# Get Mailbox owner SID from Exchange Server

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchangelib

I am using the python package exchangelib to scan a mailbox. I need to get the mailbox owner SID without connecting to the AD directly (using LDAP queries).

I couldn't find a way to do this, is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [GetDelegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/getdelegate-operation) operation can return the SID of a user, but it requires that the user is a delegate of another account, and also that you know that account beforehand.

Otherwise, I'm not aware that this is possible via EWS (and thus exchangelib).